# nano line numbers in nanorc by default

Tags: ubuntu, editors, text

"set linenumber" doesn't seem to be working.
GNU nano version 2.5.3. LinuxMint 18.02 (old because my Ubuntus -- 17.04 and 18.04 -- are broken.)
Is there another way to do it?

Comment: According to the changelog, the linenumber**s** option was added in version 2.7.1-1

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/questions/73444/how-to-show-line-numbering-in-nano-when-opening-a-file help?

Comment: No it does not. They suggest exactly that thing that doesn't seem to work. I invite you to read my OP again. I meant ""set linenumber" doesn't work."

Comment: I have since upgraded my nano to 2.9.3 (thanks to a deb I found for Ubuntu 17.04 online somewhere). I had the installer script keep my edited nanorc, which included the added "set linenumber" as well as an uncommented "set constantshow." Of course all the foregoing were displayed in a nano Without line numbers.

Comment: AFAIK the option is `linenumbers`, not `linenumber`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll try it.

Comment: I have it as linenumbers. No change

Answer (score 2):

Just open your file with line number option:

```
nano myfile.sample -l
```